# PHP foreach loop table with twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, loops, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I am having trouble implementing a `foreach` loop table into twitter Bootstrap for displaying users points from the database:

```
<ol>
<?php foreach($ranking as $key1 => $value1): ?> 
    <?php print $key1.", ".$value1['username'].$value1['points']."<br>";?>          
<?php endforeach; ?>    
</ol>
```

I did something like this:

```
<?php echo '<table class="table"><tr>';

    foreach($ranking as $key1 => $value1)
        echo '<td>', $key1, '</td>
    <td>', $value1, '</td>';

    echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem aside from the fact that you should probably write clean php

Comment: I relly dont know because it returns a mess.

Comment: I have trouble parking my car.

Comment: @KeesSonnema What car are you driving? How are you trying to park? How do your pedals look? Is it an automatic or a manual? *Basically - we need more info, OP*.

Comment: Now that you've added the table it makes even less sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is probably that you need `<li>`'s inside your `<ol>`. But I would recommend a proper rewrite. You also don't need a `<br>` with lists.

```
<ol>
<?php 
    foreach($ranking as $key1 => $value1){
        echo "<li>". key1 . ", " . $value1['username'] . $value1['points']."</li>";
    }
?>    
</ol>
```

Want a table? Do kinda of the same thing, remember, `<tr>` is a row, `<td>` is a cell. I also added the class `table` to the `table`, for [boostrap css](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables)

```
<table class="table">
<?php 
    foreach($ranking as $key1 => $value1){
        echo "<tr><td>". key1 . "</td><td>" . $value1['username'] . $value1['points']."</td></tr>";
    }
?>    
</table>
```

ps: I guessed what you wanted in a cell.

Perhaps do some more `HTML` & `PHP` tutorials and read up on some best practices

Comment: @h2ooooooo valid argument. changed it to what I actually intended of it

Comment: Was I really that unclear? probably I was an I apologise for that. Yes I wanted a simple table. Thanks for that implementation, it worked.

Comment: How can this be written if we're looking to get a row for every two returned item?

Answer (score 1):

Inside an `<ol>` needs to be one or more `<li>`s. Not lines with `<br>` at the end.